# Injecting service into factory is a good practice or not

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns

I have one service with set of functions and one factory.
Now In factory I need to use functions which are present in service.

If I inject Service as dependency in factory I can use all functions which are present in service.

But My Doubt is injecting service into factory is good practice or not?
Please help me in this !!

Comment: As long as there are not circular dependancies and you can handle any asynchronous functions, it can have as many nested services/factories (same thing) as you want. It's not just a good practice, it's what they were designed for - ["to share code across your app"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: Kindly help me out in this

Comment: What do you need help with? An example of injection? If you define your factory as `angular.factory('SomeFactory', SomeFactory);` then you can inject a service into it with `SomeFactory.$inject = ["SomeService"];` (but there are other syntaxes you can use)